# How to Retrieve Data from Firebase using Python

Tags: python, get, firebase, python-requests, patch

I'm new to Python and I would like to connect to Firebase using Python. I can successfully add and modify Firebase using `put()` and `patch()`, but I can't find a way to retrieve my data from Firebase.

**Code:**

```
import serial
import time
import requests
import json

firebase_url = 'https://testing1639.firebaseio.com'

#Connect to Serial Port for communication
ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0', 9600)

#Setup a loop to send temperature values at fixed intervals in seconds
fixed_interval = 2

while 1:
    try:
         #Temperature value obtained from Arduino + LM35 Temp Sensor
         temperature_c = ser.readline()
         #Current time and date
         time_hhmmss = time.strftime('%H:%M:%S')
         date_mmddyyyy = time.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')

         #Current location name
         temperature_location = 'Mumbai-Kandivali' ;

         print temperature_c + ',' + time_hhmmss + ',' + date_mmddyyyy + ',' + temperature_location

         #Insert record
         data = {'date':date_mmddyyyy,'time':time_hhmmss,'value':temperature_c}

         result = requests.post(firebase_url + '/' + temperature_location + '/temperature.json', data=json.dumps(data))

         #Insert record
         print 'Record inserted. Result Code = ' + str(result.status_code) + ',' + result.text
         time.sleep(fixed_interval)

    except IOError:
        print('Error! Something went wrong.')
        time.sleep(fixed_interval)
```

How can I modify it to retrieve the data?

Comment: There are a few libraries that are commonly used. See http://ozgur.github.io/python-firebase/ and   https://github.com/mikexstudios/python-firebase. Both are mentioned here https://www.firebase.com/docs/rest/quickstart.html. If you have problems with them, post what you've tried and we can better help.

Comment: I'll try them and see. Thanks a lot for the response

Comment: Hi, did you ever get your python script to work without the libraries? Problem with these libraries is that they become outdated. Right now firebase tech says they have an issue with that particular library. So I'm thinking it would be safer to access their rest api directly from python.

Answer (score 10):

### Installation

```
pip install firebase
```

#### Python Version

Firebase was written for python 3 and above and will not work correctly with python 2.

#### Add Firebase to your Application

Your Google's Firebase configuration data can be found on [Firebase](https://console.firebase.google.com) > Settings > Project Settings *Scroll to bottom* > Add to web app > config

For use with only user based authentication we can create the following configuration:

```py
from firebase import Firebase

config = {
  "apiKey": "apiKey",
  "authDomain": "projectId.firebaseapp.com",
  "databaseURL": "https://databaseName.firebaseio.com",
  "storageBucket": "projectId.appspot.com"
}

firebase = Firebase(config)
```

### Authentication

The `sign_in_with_email_and_password()` method will return user data including a token you can use to adhere to security rules.

Each of the following methods accepts a user token: `get()`, `push()`, `set()`, `update()`, `remove()` and `stream()`.

```py
# Get a reference to the auth service
auth = firebase.auth()

# Log the user in
user = auth.sign_in_with_email_and_password(email, password)

# Get a reference to the database service
db = firebase.database()

# data to save
data = {
    "name": "Joe Tilsed"
}

# Pass the user's idToken to the push method
results = db.child("users").push(data, user['idToken'])
```

### Database

You can build paths to your data by using the `child()` method.

```py
db = firebase.database()
db.child("users").child("Joe")
```

#### Save Data

push

To save data with a unique, auto-generated, timestamp-based key, use the `push()` method.

```py
data = {"name": "Joe Tilsed"}
db.child("users").push(data)
```

set

To create your own keys use the `set()` method. The key in the example below is "Joe".

```py
data = {"name": "Joe Tilsed"}
db.child("users").child("Joe").set(data)
```

update

To update data for an existing entry use the `update()` method.

```py
db.child("users").child("Joe").update({"name": "Joe W Tilsed"})
```

remove

To delete data for an existing entry use the `remove()` method.

```py
db.child("users").child("Joe").remove()
```

#### Retrieve Data

val

Queries return a FirebaseResponse object. Calling `val()` on these objects returns the query data.

```
users = db.child("users").get()
print(users.val())

>> {"Joe": {"name": "Joe Tilsed"}, "Syd": {"name": "Sydney Cox"}}
```

key

Calling `key()` returns the key for the query data.

```
user = db.child("users").get()
print(user.key())

>> users
```

each

Returns a list of objects on each of which you can call `val()` and `key()`.

```
all_users = db.child("users").get()
for user in all_users.each():
    print(user.key())

    >> Joe 

    print(user.val())   

    >> {name": "Joe Tilsed"}
```

get

To return data from a path simply call the `get()` method.

```py
all_users = db.child("users").get()
```

Hope this helps. Full docs: https://pypi.org/project/firebase/

Answer (score 1):

I have something like this which is working

firebase_url = 'https://xyz.firebaseio.com/'

client_name = 'Mumbai-Kandivali'

class MainPage(webapp.RequestHandler):

```
def get(self):
    self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'     
    url = firebase_url + '/' + client_name + '/temperature.json'        
    json_object = json.load(urllib2.urlopen(url))
    json.dump(json_object,  self.response.out ) #this will go to frontend
```

Hope this help...However I am working on fetching "import firebase" in python and then perform operation

Answer (score 0):

import firebase_admin
from firebase_admin import credentials, db

cred = credentials.Certificate("cred.json") firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred,{    'databaseURL':'https://***your_db_url.**region**.firebasedatabase.app' })

ref = db.reference("/")
#add data in your firebase db data = ref.child('posts').push({  "Books":    {       "Best_Sellers": -1  } })

#get data from firebase db
data_1 = ref.child('posts').get()

#itterate your data
for x,y in data_1.items():
print(x,y)